# Division overlapping the other division

Tags: html, css

I use a div tag but my about division is still overlapping my navbar division.

[image: Output]

This is my demo:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap');
body {
  background: url(boba.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1170px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.menu ul li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu ul li:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
}

.menu ul li:nth-child(2) {
  float: left;
}

.menu ul li:nth-child(3) {
  float: left;
}

.menu ul li a {
  color: #262626;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #77DF79;
  color: black;
}

#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  margin-left: -205px;
}

#descrip p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#descrip h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

.button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #56ab2f 0%, #a8e063 51%, #56ab2f 100%);
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}

.slicknav_menu {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .slicknav_menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    background-image: url(m3.jpg);
  }
  .button {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}

.about {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Smile to Go! </title>
  <link rel="icon" href="logo1.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slicknav.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="logo1.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbar">

      <div class="menu">
        <ul id="list">
          <li> <a href="index.html" class="active"> Home </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> About </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Products </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Branches </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Gallery </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Contact </a> </li>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="descrip">
      <h1> Smile to Go! </h1>
      <p>Smile to go milktea serves a wide variety of tasy and refreshing authentic pearl milktea drinks. uaranteed made from 100% freshly brewed loose-leaf teas of high quality for an overall healthier lifestyle. We also serve variety of iced coffees,slush,cream
        and latte drinks and toppings for your freshly cool drinks!.</p>
      <button type="button" class="button"> Learn More </button>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>


    <div class="about">
      <hr>
      <h1> Welcome to Smile to Go!</h1>
      <p> Sip up a refreshin milktea that will give you a large smile on your face!<br> Enjoy different variety of coffees, tea,slush and cream lattes. <br>Share the cool refreshing drink now to your friends and families. <br>Visit us on our stores nationwide!</p>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.slicknav.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#list').slicknav();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>

<!----- references and resources
https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
https://www.facebook.com/SmileToGoHongKong/
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbwXnUipZsLfUckBPsC7Jog
https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hp-LP8Nv18s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svv7jOxaSzw
https://slicknav.io/----->
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap');
body {
  background: url(boba.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1170px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.menu ul li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu ul li:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
}

.menu ul li:nth-child(2) {
  float: left;
}

.menu ul li:nth-child(3) {
  float: left;
}

.menu ul li a {
  color: #262626;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #77DF79;
  color: black;
}

#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  margin-left: -205px;
}

#descrip{text-align:center;}

#descrip p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#descrip h1 {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

.button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #56ab2f 0%, #a8e063 51%, #56ab2f 100%);
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-position: right center;
}

.slicknav_menu {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .slicknav_menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    background-image: url(m3.jpg);
  }
  .button {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}

.about {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Smile to Go! </title>
  <link rel="icon" href="logo1.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slicknav.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
</head>

<body>

  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="logo1.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbar">

      <div class="menu">
        <ul id="list">
          <li> <a href="index.html" class="active"> Home </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> About </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Products </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Branches </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Gallery </a> </li>
          <li> <a href="index.html"> Contact </a> </li>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="descrip">
      <h1> Smile to Go! </h1>
      <p>Smile to go milktea serves a wide variety of tasy and refreshing authentic pearl milktea drinks. uaranteed made from 100% freshly brewed loose-leaf teas of high quality for an overall healthier lifestyle. We also serve variety of iced coffees,slush,cream
        and latte drinks and toppings for your freshly cool drinks!.</p>
      <button type="button" class="button"> Learn More </button>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>


    <div class="about">
      <hr>
      <h1> Welcome to Smile to Go!</h1>
      <p> Sip up a refreshin milktea that will give you a large smile on your face!<br> Enjoy different variety of coffees, tea,slush and cream lattes. <br>Share the cool refreshing drink now to your friends and families. <br>Visit us on our stores nationwide!</p>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.slicknav.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#list').slicknav();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! May i know where did i get wrong? I am still learning about basics of css and html

Comment: No problem, keep going

Answer (score 0):

so I will explain cause i have been in your place before ..
first you are making the elements inside #descrip position absolute  and that's okay if u add position relative and a height to #descrip .. cause now the elements are flowing out of that #descrip container and that container's height is small so the about is coming after it therefore under the element 
 what would be better is using the margins and so on to place the element in the place u want .. read about margin auto also is really help full .. and be careful with float  .. read about flex box also really helpful

Comment: Thank you so much sir for the explanations and other helpful stuff!